# Is entity framework running a db query with every .Count() method called in my code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a loop in my razor syntax that looks something like this. And in each loop I'm getting a count of the registered students for a class. Will a db query be called/executed to acquire this count? Should I keep a int value of this number so that a db call doesn't have to be made with each call to it. My loop might be 15-20 per page.

```
foreach (var space in Model.Spaces)
{
    // do some stuff
    @{ var studentCount = @space.RegisteredStudents.Count(); }
}
```

Note - registeredstudents looks like this in another entity that I'm pulling from the db when getting my results. So registeredstudents has its own table.

```
public virtual ICollection<Student.RegisteredStudent> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tip: Do not pass `IQueryable` objects to ASP.NET MVC Razor views. Instead pass pre-populated `List<T>` collections. Views should not initiate DB query execution, even indirectly.

Comment: As suggested in the comment by @Dai, you need to materialize your data and pass it to your view so that your view will entirely process the data from within the memory - without making a call to the database server. If you do ToList() on the dbset while querying your EF context, your data will be available in the memory for the application to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Entity Framework model classes as view-model objects in ASP.NET MVC. While often they contain the data you want to display it violates aspects of MVVM design, one example is the case you're seeing where your pages are (indirectly) executing DB queries.

Instead create a dedicated view-model class for each view which explicitly contains the data you want. These can be simple POCO classes.

I personally prefer to put read-only data in `ViewData` instead of the view's `Model` property, I also subclass `ViewData` to add strongly-typed properties, but this is down to personal preference.

In your case:

#### ViewModels

```
class SpacesViewModel {
    public IList<SpaceViewModel> Spaces { get; set; }
}
class SpaceViewModel {
    public Int32 StudentCount { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller action

```
public ActionResult View() {

    IQueryable<Spaces> dbSpaces = ... // get `Spaces` instance from Entity Framework

    SpacesViewModel vm = new SpacesViewModel();
    vm.Spaces = dbSpaces.Select(
        dbSpace => new SpaceViewModel() {
            StudentCount = dbSpace.RegisteredStudents.Count();
        }
    ).ToList();

    return this.View( vm );
}
```

#### View

```
@model SpacesViewModel

@foreach(SpaceViewModel space in Model.Spaces) {
    @space.StudentCount
}
```

Comment: but when you call dbSpace.RegisteredStudents.Count(); this makes a call N number of times to the db right? So if I have 30 spaceviewmodel's then the db will be called 30 times? right?

Comment: @user1186050 Correct. But that is intentional and there is no way around that because you have 30 different values to return. However the queries are being executed from within the controller action and not the view, which is a better application design.

Comment: @user1186050 The `.Count()` query is cheap, though I'll agree your application is being chatty with your database. You might want to consider a different query that does a `SELECT SpaceId, COUNT(*) FROM RegisteredStudents GROUP BY SpaceId `, that way you only need to execute 1 query which will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're doing in your code. Based merely on the code you provided, yes, you're issuing a SELECT COUNT for each `space`. However, if in your controller you were to do something like:

```
var spaces = db.Spaces.Included("RegisteredStudents");
```

Then, the students are included in the query. When you later call `Count` it will merely do an in-memory count of the students. It's all in the context. After you deal with this stuff for some time, you can spot places where extra queries will get issued at a glance. In the meantime, I recommend installing some like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It's 100% free and, among other awesome things, it will let you see every single query that's issued to render your page. If you see oddly high amounts of queries, then, that'll be your clue you're doing something inefficient, like issuing a count for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: To note is... this will not work because of the usual LINQ behavior. Even when you include the Students, this will still return an IQueryable<T> object, so the query will be run later in the foreach() call. only when you force EF to execute the query, using .ToList(), the query will be executed right away and following queries will be done in-memory.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it "will not work". True, the query won't be evaluated until you try to do something with it, but that's accomplished by attempting to iterate it. As soon as you do that, the query is run and *all* the counts are run in memory. So, really, you've just delayed execution of the query from the controller until the view, but there's still only a single query either way.

Comment: yep, I thought the same. however, in foreach you will have a call to db in each run.

Comment: Why would this only run in memory? So are you saying it doesn't make do calls to get the count???

Comment: It would only run in memory if you included the relevant relationship you're counting. If you do that, then the query joins the related table. Afterwards, EF already has all the data. It's not going to issue a database query to get a count of it; it's just going to count the items in the collection like you would with any other in memory collection.

Answer (score -2):

i've taken a different approach. I'm keeping track of the count of registered users, by userid, inside a string (ex. "123,456,789") that is an entity property. Now I just have to get this column value with the rest of the columns from the SpaceEvent entity and split it on ',' to get each id. Originally I wanted to get each id so that I could loop through them in razor and create N slides for a bootstrap carousel. This approach seems to work great to save the N calls to the database for fetching each RegisteredStudent count(). I don't know if there is a better approach and this is a little more tedious when registering a student but it saves lots of db calls.

Comment: just want to know why this was down voted? Although it might not be best practice to do this, I've saved myself hundreds of db calls per get call on my site.

Comment: There's other ways you could save the DB calls when doing counts and keeping counts in stored or worse, even, static id references in a string, breaks normalization. You now have a column that you must keep track of and always assure that it is updated and in line with the rest of the database. You might was well just start storing stuff in text files and throw the DB out the window.